# Android Tweet and redirect to a handle in Browser using Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, twitter

I am trying to tweet and redirect to a handle once user tweet successfully through browser only(not twitter native application).

```
I have found two set of api's for achieving this:-
1).Redirect to a twitter handle/page 

String url = "https://www.twitter.com/" + @Android ;
Intent intent1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(intent1);

//Works successfully

2). //Twitter sharing
String tweetUrl = String.format("https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=@clinker70723 This Tweet text is from Android&url=https://www.google.com",

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(tweetUrl));
startActivity(intent);

//Tweet using web browser,ask to login if user is not logged in

Is there any API available which will redirect to a twitter handle from browser once tweet is successful.Basically API should provide both the functionality mentioned above.

THANKS IN ADVANCE!!!
```